# How to set custom time zone in Rails? "-03:30GMT"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I know we can set time zone with

Time.zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"

But how to set with UTC/GMT time, I want to set time zone to **-03:30GMT**, but I cant find any place which lies in that time zone, so how to set it by giving values?

Answer (score 0):

try this. this will work

```
Time.zone = -12600
```

Comment: No this isn't what I asked for. I want to set time zone to "-03:30GMT", how to do that?

Comment: Thanks, but it is setting time as -02:30GMT.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the full list of timezones from the library

```
    ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map.values.collect { |z| z.tzinfo.name }.compact.uniq.each do |tz|
      puts "#{ActiveSupport::TimeZone.seconds_to_utc_offset(Time.now.in_time_zone(tz).utc_offset)}\t#{tz}"
    end; nil
```

> I cant find any place which lies in that time zone

It looks like all zones are covered

Comment: Thanks, but the list it generated doesn't contain time zone of -03:30GMT. which is time zone of "America/St_Johns" with out day light savings.